# Standardize Xamarin Android Styles.xml and ResourceDictionary

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to avoid duplicate declaration of style definitions in both android `styles.xml` and `resourcedictionary`. For example,

In Android `styles.xml`, I've the following to change the default theme's primary color

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyDefaultTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
    
    <color name="colorPrimary">#0E80FF</color>
</resources>
```

And in `DefaultResourceDictionary.xaml`, I've the following so that my XF's controls uses the same color as defined in `styles.xml`:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Color x:Key="colorPrimary">#0E80FF</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

On top of my head, I can think of doing some `PreBuild` actions to invoke `XmlPoke` to insert the value from `ResourceDictionary` into `styles.xml`.

Is there any less complicated ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add styles in the App Class.
Example adding this in the App.xaml file

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#512bdf</Color>
            <Color x:Key="SecondaryColor">White</Color>

            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryColor}" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="14,10" />
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Comment: doesn't address my question. Yes, I can add `PrimaryColor` in my `App.xaml`, but I will still need to have a duplicate entry in `styles.xml` for android

Comment: `but I will still need to have a duplicate entry in styles.xml for android`  Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. What are you trying to achieve?Can you elaborate on that?